# Diagram hasse in natural.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

Is there a natural to other than 0 such that in the diagram of Hasse of natural with divisibility there is a natural between a and 0?

Comment: I'm not really clear exactly what you are asking for, would it be possible to clarify? One thing to keep in mind is that every natural number divides $0$ so $0$ would be at the top of the hasse diagram. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: No wonder that if there is a different number of 0 such that in diagram natural numbers divisibility, there is some number between zero and the selected element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be any natural number, we want to show that there exists a natural number $b$ such that $b$ is between $a$ and $0$ in the Hasse diagram.

Since the relationship is divisibility, we want either $a | b$ and $b | 0$ **or** $0 | b$ and $b | a$. It turns out that **every** natural number divides into $0$, so we can just pick any multiple of $a$, say $2a$, then
$$a | 2a \text{ and } 2a | 0.$$

Notice that I made the claim that every natural number $x$ divides into $0$, i.e. $x|0$. To show this is true, it suffices to show that there is an integer $k$ such that $xk = 0$; we can simply pick $k=0$ to make this equation true thus $x|0$.